# Replace chars after column X

Tags: awk, sed

Lets say my data looks like this

```
iqwertyuiop
```

and I want to replace all the letters i after column 3 with a Z.. so my output would look like this

```
iqwertyuZop
```

How can I do this with sed or awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "column" but maybe this is what you want using GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ echo iqwertyuiop | awk '{print substr($0,1,3) gensub(/i/,"Z","g",substr($0,4))}'
iqwertyuZop
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl is handy for this: you can *assign* to a substring

```
$ echo "iiiiii" | perl -pe 'substr($_,3) =~ s/i/Z/g'
iiiZZZ
```

Answer (score 1):

The most intuitive way would be to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS=FS}{for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="i"){$i="Z"}}}1' file
```

`FS=""` splits the input string by characters into fields. We iterate trough character/field 4 to end and replace `i` by `Z`.

The final `1` evaluates to `true` and make `awk` print the modified input line.

---

With `sed` it looks not very intutive but still it is possible:

```
sed -r '
    h                      # Backup the current line in hold buffer
    s/.{3}//               # Remove the first three characters
    s/i/Z/g                # Replace all i by Z
    G                      # Append the contents of the hold buffer to the pattern buffer (this adds a newline between them)
    s/(.*)\n(.{3}).*/\2\1/ # Remove that newline ^^^ and assemble the result
' file
```

Comment: Can't you 1) use `y/i/Z/` (saves a full character!) 2) instead of `x;s;G;s` do `G;s/(.*)\n(...).*/\2\1/`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. 1) The `y` command requires a `;` after it in a multiline version if there is a comment after it. Don't ask me why. 2) Good point! Added that

Answer (score 1):

This would totally be ideal for the `tr` command, if only you didn't have the requirement that the first 3 characters remain untouched.

However, if you are okay using some bash tricks plus `cut` and `paste`, you can split the file into two parts and paste them back together afterwords:

```
paste -d'\0' <(cut -c-3 foo) <(cut -c4- foo | tr i Z)
```

The above uses `paste` to rejoin together the two parts of the file that get split with `cut`.  The second section is piped through `tr` to translate i's to Z's.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Here's a short-and-simple way to accomplish the task using GNU sed:

```
sed -r -e ':a;s/^(...)([^i]*)i/\1\2Z/g;ta'
```

This entails looping (`t`), and so would not be as efficient as non-looping approaches.  The above can also be written using escaped parentheses instead of unescaped characters, and so there is no real need for the -r option.  Other implementations of sed should (in principle) be up to the task as well, but your MMV.

(2) It's easy enough to use "old awk" as well:

```
awk '{s=substr($0,4);gsub(/i/,"Z",s); print substr($0,1,3) s}'
```